# Why component dont display variable of another component?

Tags: angular

I have 2 components: `AppComponent` and export class `InnerComponent`. `AppComponent` embed `InnerComponent` via `@ViewChild`. After that i need display to console variables value from `InnerComponent`. However i get error message to console because this.InnerComponent is undefined.

Please help me display `a` variable to console from `AppComponent`.

AppComponent:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { InnerComponent } from './inner/inner.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(InnerComponent) innerComponent: InnerComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.innerComponent); // undefined
    console.log(this.innerComponent.a); // error
  }
}
```

InnerComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inner',
  templateUrl: './inner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inner.component.css'],
})
export class InnerComponent {
  a = 200;
}`enter code here`
```

[live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/at-ng-14-router-meglca?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app.component.html` template doesn't actually contain the `<app-inner>` component. If you haven't put it in the template, it's not a child you can select with `@ViewChild`

Your template looks like this:

```html
<div class="app">app:</div>
```

But it should look like this so the element can be selected

```html
<div class="app">
  app:
  <app-inner></app-inner>
</div>
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/at-ng-14-router-urpfqy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Finner%2Finner.component.ts)